# Update duplicate emails to a different value

Tags: mysql

I have a user table where the "email" column is not `UNIQUE`. Unfortunately there are records with duplicate emails.

I need to import this table into another user table where the "email" column is `UNIQUE`.

I'm thinking to update any duplicate email to a different value so that there are no more duplicates.

For example, if I have three records with the same email "example@example.com." Then keep one of them and update the other two to something like "example@example.com[a random string]."

What SQL statements should I run to achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Table for testing Gordon's solution -

[image]

Result -

[image]

Comment: You are just loose your users... Is this in the production?

Comment: [Distinct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Comment: do you have an `auto_increment` in this table? Get a backup of that table. Also determine if your changes are about to violate and FK's in place (for afterwards, when you do the deletes). Fix the data, do the deletes on the non-used dupes. Put the unique key in place for `email`

Comment: So, just changing the emails still keeps a lot of junk in your system. I would not change emails. I would collapse them for integrity of your data. Clean and keep important stuff before you lose the associated data. Then purge the unused ones (the deletes). Then get the unique index in place.

Comment: Understood. This is for internal use and usually it's couple/family who use the same email, but they are different identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
select concat(u.email,
              (case when @e = email then concat('[', @rn := @rn + 1, ']')
                    when (@e := email) is null then '' -- never happens
                    when (@rn := 1) is null then '' -- never happens
                    else ''
               end))
from users u cross join
     (select @e := '', @rn := 0) params
order by u.email;
```

EDIT:

Hmmm, the above didn't work in SQL Fiddle, but this version [does](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffcecf/9):

```
select concat(u.email,
              if(@e = u.email, concat('[', @rn := @rn + 1, ']'),
                 if(@e := u.email, if(@rn := 1, '', ''), '')
                )
             ), @e, @rn
from users u cross join
     (select @e := '', @rn := 0) params
order by u.email;
```

Comment: It gave me error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from test u cross join (select @e := '', @rn := 0) params order by u.email ' at line 7`

Comment: BTW, I like this approach better than the embedded `if` statements you've used before.  Much cleaner to understand what's going on (plus sets rn in a single clause).

Comment: Thanks, but still got this: `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`

Comment: And if runs successfully, does this statement update the table? Cuz that's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn . . . There is no need to update the table.  You can use this `select` to populate the second table.  As for the collations, you will need to use `COLLATE` to set an appropriate collation (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html).  It is unusual for a column to have a different collation from the server, but it is useful under some circumstances.

Comment: Should the first `@e = email` be `@e := email` instead? That removes the error, but then it just selects the email column as it is.

Comment: Doing more testing. It seems if the email value is just an integer, then it works, but apparently the real cases the email will not be an integer....

Comment: @Shawn . . . There is nothing in this code that suggests that `email` is an integer.  Are you sure you are setting `@e` to a string in the `params` subquery?

Comment: I'm running the exact same query except that changing the first `@e = email` to `@e := email`.

Comment: See my updated question for the table and result I got. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, man. The update works if I change `email` collation to `utf8_general_ci`. If it's `utf8_unicode_ci`, it gives error. Why is this sql only works for `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: I see what you mean. My server connection collation is `utf8_general_ci`, but my column is `utf8_unicode_ci`. From phpMyAdmin it seems I can temporarily change server connection collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`, but not sure how to permanently change it....